# Can't start vscode on windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to start vscode exe file on windows 7, but I have some errors:

```
$ "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --verbose

{ errorCode: 'load',
  moduleId: 'semver',
  neededBy: [ 'vs/platform/extensions/node/extensionValidator' ],
  detail:
   { Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
       ...
   },
{ errorCode: 'load',
  moduleId: 'spdlog',
  neededBy: [ 'vs/platform/log/node/spdlogService' ],
  detail:
   { Error: Cannot find module 'bindings'
      ... }
```

Comment: It's pretty clear vscode is failing to find your extensions.

Comment: Where do you start it from ? What is $ ?

Comment: the dollar symbol here means that it is git bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by reinstalling the VSCode. My IDE settings were saved automatic.

Comment: settings are not deleted upon uninstallation